# Sort within select box using option_groups_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and am using option_groups_from_collection_for_select to create a select box that will display a list of facilities sorted by neighborhood. I want both the list of neighborhoods and the list of facilities in each neighborhood to be sorted alphabetically by name.  (Neighborhood has_many :facilities and Facility belongs_to :neighborhood).

Here's my code, which sorts the neighborhoods, but not the facilities in each neighborhood.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<%= f.select :facility_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select (Neighborhood.order("name"), :facilities, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/ has some info on how to work with collection select.  One way of achieving what you want is to create a method in your model which sorts as you like it to be.  Examples of using custom methods are given in the blog post.

Comment: The answer to your problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856010/option-groups-from-collection-for-select-specific-method-group/21859622