# option_groups_from_collection_for_select specific method group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to make a dynamic select form into ActiveAdmin.
Let say a User has multiple Orders. And each Order has an attribute pay (boolean). 
After selecting the User the next seleciton is the order pay by this user.

```
option_groups_from_collection_for_select(User.order(:email), :orders, :email, :id, :name)
```

But i don't get how to display only the payed orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method on the `User` model that will replace the `:orders` argument you're passing in. This method should return the `orders` that are payed.

Try using an association declaration (this will add the method for you):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :paid_orders, class_name: 'Order', -> { where pay: true }
end
```

Now your `user` instances will have a `paid_orders` method that returns `orders` where their `pay` attribute is `true`.

Now change your form helper to:

```
option_groups_from_collection_for_select(User.order(:email), :paid_orders, :email, :id, :name)
```

That should do it.

The idea here is that the `:paid_orders` argument is the name of a method on an instance of `User`. You are free to define any method you'd like, even manually as so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def paid_orders
    orders.where pay: true
  end
end
```